# Node js Data from the ckeditor is showing with HTML tags in the ejs file

Tags: node.js, ckeditor

I'm facing a issue with the ckeditor in my nodejs code when I input data using ckeditor the data is submitted with the HTML tags in the database(phpmyadmin) from there when I'm trying to fetch the data in the ejs file I have tried the strip tags and sanitizer but nothing worked.

Comment: You should add some of your code, and show us what you have already tried. Also, some grammar improvements and better text formatting would help, because others can read your post better, which, hopefully, results in more answers.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the tag `<%- %>` instead of `<%= %>`?
`<%-` escapes HTML by default (therefore your `br` tag is changed to it's escaped equivalent).